# Wrapping comments with line breaks in PyCharm

Tags: intellij-idea, formatting, comments, keyboard-shortcuts, pycharm

I have comments that gets balloon `(PEP 8: Line too long ... > 120)`
I wish there was a command that will wrap the lines with few keystrokes.
Right now, even if I type <kbd>Alt+Enter</kbd> and press <kbd>enter</kbd> on `Reformat file`, nothing actually changes. Is there a setting or plugin I could use to accomplish the formatting easily?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Firstly, reformatting won't work, not in Python at least, where whitespace is important. PyCharm's "Wrap when typing reaches right margin" option is what you're looking for. Now this will not work when you copy and paste code, but in the places where it gives you trouble, just press enter, and it will work.

[image: Screenshot of where to turn on PyCharm "Wrap when typing reaches right margin" option]

Comment: Comments and docstrings are two places where whitespace is not important.  It would be nice if PyCharm could do a good job of wrapping them.  (It can do the basic job...)

Answer (score 64):

Under the `Edit` menu, there is a `Fill Paragraph` option, which does what I believe you want.  You can assign a key command to this in `Preferences`, under `Appearance & Behavior` -> `Keymap` (search for "fill").

Personally, I choose first stroke Esc, second stroke Q, because that's what I've always used in Emacs...

Comment: This is actually exactly what I was looking for and probably exactly what the OP was looking for, too.
The accepted answer doesn't account for the fact that the OP was looking to autowrap _comments_ where whitespace is usually not important (other than a manual newline here and there).

Comment: For some reason 'fill paragraph' does not work if any text is selected. The cursor must just be in the paragraph somewhere.

Comment: This breaks docstrings built with reStructuredText. ([PY-28838](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-28838))

Comment: Thank you. I have reported the issue and reposed my comment with a link to the issue page.

Comment: Can you change the width of the paragraph?

Comment: There is a [feature request that you could vote for](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-15700), or you could try [this plugin](https://github.com/abrookins/WrapToColumn).

Comment: Actually, the comment here re: fill paragraph not working if text was selected was helpful to me. Agreed that it would be much more helpful to make a bug report, though.

Comment: @Stevoisiak, you might try adding `# language=rst prefix="    "` on the line immediately before any docstring with RST.

Answer (score 19):

To be able to auto-reformat comments (and code, for that matter) to honor a right margin after the fact, go into Project Settings under Code Style and then further under Python.  Click the Wrapping and Braces tab, and check the "Ensure right margin is not exceeded" checkbox.

Now if you select a region of lines and then run the Code/Reformat Code... command, PyCharm will do its best to wrap the comments or code appropriately.

You will probably have to do some tweaking of the results to suit your stylistic taste.  For example, I wish PyCharm would do aggressive filling of text in block comments, at least optionally so.

PyCharm will not reformat code such that it becomes invalid Python, so sometimes it will still leave a line longer than the margin (120 or whatever you set under Project Settings/Code Style/General).

[image]

Answer (score 10):

With recent PyCharm this now is located at "Editor -> Code Style", with the checkbox named "Wrap on typing" 
[image]

The Screenshot shows PyCharm version 2016.2.1 Professional.

Comment: This is still the way in 2020.

Answer (score 4):

Updated Answer:
Use "soft wraps." You can search for it in the help bar.

View > Active Editor > Use Soft Wraps

It won't work for existing text or text that's copied in, but will for any newly typed text.