# Pycharm Formatting Restructured Text Line Breaks

Tags: pycharm

Writing a blog using Pelican and all my static files are .rst format. I write them in the Pycharm IDE, but I feel like I'm back in the type writer age by constantly hitting enter to go to the next line. Is there some way PyCharm can auto format the line breaks such that a large body of text is broken up to each line's maximum characters?

TLDR;
I'm manually making sure each line is <80 characters. I want PyCharm to do this automatically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wrapping comments with line breaks in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17196836/wrapping-comments-with-line-breaks-in-pycharm)

Answer (score 2):

Use "soft wraps." You can search for it in the help bar.

View > Active Editor > Use Soft Wraps

It won't work for existing .rst files or text that's copied in, but will for any newly typed text.

Comment: What about reformatting by including hard wraps. `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `L` works on a `*.md` file both not on a `*.rst` file. Is this a bug or am I missing a setting?