# In PyCharm, keeping a certain page width without constantly editing line breaks or using word wrap

Tags: ide, pycharm, editor, comments

This problem has bothered me since I began programming many years ago, and I figured I would ask you all what you think. I've been told this problem is tool-specific, so this question is about doing it in PyCharm.

Say you are not using word-wrap. Now you need to edit a bunch of multiline comments like:

```
# I had some thoughts here which I thought I
# would share. They're a bit long, so I need
# to extend them across several lines.
```

Then say you want to edit the comment. So here's your edit:

```
# I had some thoughts here about programming best practices which I thought I
# would share. They're a bit long, so I need
# to extend them across several lines.
```

Oops, your new text makes the first line quite long. Let's break that into a new line:

```
# I had some thoughts here about programming 
# best practices which I thought I
# would share. They're a bit long, so I need
# to extend them across several lines.
```

Hmm that second line is a bit short, let's bring some text up from the third line:

```
# I had some thoughts here about programming 
# best practices which I thought I would share. 
# They're a bit long, so I need
# to extend them across several lines.
```

Uh-oh, now that third line is too short, let's bring text up from the fourth line:

```
# I had some thoughts here about programming 
# best practices which I thought I would share. 
# They're a bit long, so I need to extend them 
# across several lines.
```

All done. But that was annoying, right? I can't believe I took the time to post this question. But I feel like I'm spending too much time fixing comments like this, and I wonder if I'm missing a better solution. Have any editors implemented one?

The natural answer is "add word wrap." But in word-wrap, unless I'm misunderstanding it, you'd just have one really long line beginning with # per paragraph, and anybody reading your code without word-wrap capabilities will hate you.

Here is how I think this question is different from the linked question: I'd like to enforce a certain width for comments, regardless of what column they happen to be on (e.g. max width 60, so comments starting on line 0 can't extend beyond line 60, but comments starting on line 30 can't extend beyond line 90, etc). This is because comment readability really has to do with how wide they are.

This is different from merely wrapping at column X because then your comments will be different widths depending on how much indentation they have.

Additionally, I don't really want to change the width of my code with this solution, although I'll do it if I have to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wrapping comments with line breaks in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17196836/wrapping-comments-with-line-breaks-in-pycharm)

Comment: Sorry, I did search but didn't see that one. Anyway what I was really hoping for was to enforce a certain width for comments, regardless of what column they happen to be on (e.g. max width 60, so comments starting on line 0 can't extend beyond line 60, but comments starting on line 30 can't extend beyond line 90, etc). This is because comment readability really has to do with how wide they are.

Comment: Edited question to explain why it's not a 100% duplicate, although I might have to resort to those answers if I can't get exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: There was a popup at the top that asked me to choose if the other question was a duplicate, and I wanted to say no, but it looks like the option was taken away. Oh well.